# Visual Studio throws no warning when first element inside grid has ColumnSpan or RowSpan out of range

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, exception, warnings

When inside a grid the first element has ColumnSpan or RowSpan out of range VS doesn't throw any warning or exception.

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border Background="yellow" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="7"/> //Columnspan and RowSpan are of out of range but VS doesn't show any warning
  </Grid>
```

Only if i define the Grid.Column and Grid.Row in the element `<Border Background="yellow" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="7" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>`, VS shows my a warning but the xaml code still runs without any exception.

If the row and column are not defined in the first element of the grid, it automatically sets both to zero.

Shouldn't a warning be shown even if Grid.Row and Grid.Column are not set manually but Grid.ColumnSpan and Grid.RowSpan are out of range?

Comment: This is how MS designed it. Why do you want to see an exception in this case?

Comment: @Sham because the spans are both out of range and VS throws a exception when i set column and row manually

Comment: It's perfectly valid to set ColumnSpan or RowSpan to values greater than the actual number of columns or rows, since columns or rows may be added dynamically. There is certainly no exception thrown, I do not even see a warning.

Comment: Can you put up the code that throws the exception in an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't a warning be shown

No because a greater span value means it spans all and works as intended.

> because the spans are both out of range and VS throws a exception when i set column and row manually

That is unrelated to a wrong value in a span property; if not garbage in, garbage out. XAML is primarily a design time operation. Values have to be kept in sync with changes provided. Hence...user error situation.